# Problem with tracking tag badge

Tags: support, tags, tag-badges, badge-progress

On my profile, when I try to edit the tag badge I am aiming for, there is only one tag option. Do you need to unlock other tags?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can only track tag badges for tags for which you've posted at least one post (answer or question). If you haven't posted yet, you can't track a tag badge at all. Due to [caching](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/), it may take some time (at most 24 hours) for tag badges to become available.

Comment: But Ive posted answers in many categories

Comment: Yeah, but not here on Meta Stack Exchange, which is a separate site.

Comment: But when I go to another site and try to track tag badges, it only allows one when I have answered many!

Comment: Ah, I see now. It's a caching issue.

Comment: A what？What is caching？

Comment: Tag scores aren't updated real time, but periodically. It may take up to 24 hours for those to be recalculated.

Comment: Oh no wonder I joined Yesterday