# Next Tag Badge Selector doesn't show all available choices

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tag-badges

There is no way to choose some tag badges even though ones with equal or fewer votes are choosable some are simply missing.

[image: Tag Badge Selector]

Notice that I can choose to track philosophy but not explainable-ai ***or*** image-recognition but not deep-network, though convolutional-neural-networks and computer-vision are available - yet each group has the same number of votes.

I have [15 tags](https://ai.stackexchange.com/users/17742/rob?tab=tags), yet most aren't visible. Same bug occurs on Data Science, Engineering, Phychology & Neuroscience, etc.

Not related or helpful Q&A's:

[Why aren't all the badges shown on the track menu?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/263610/282094)

[How can I see my progress for different badges?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/256447/282094)

[Problem with tracking tag badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/310156/282094)

[How do "badges" work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17853/282094)

Comment: The badges you can't track all correspond to tags with fewer than 100 questions, which are ineligible for tag badges.

Comment: I edited the [FAQ - How do badges work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17854/282094) to make it clearer and address the [comments to where the above question is linked to as a dupe](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/323089/what-criteria-must-a-badge-meet-to-be-tracked#comment1056541_323090). Another sign-post now points the way. Thanks, both.